# Why can't I boot from a usb?

Tags: installation, boot, usb

I generated a brand new (reformatted) USB Key to boot on Ubuntu.
I generated the USB Key using the internet procedure accessing it from a Windows 7 PC with Google Chrome.
I generated the USB KEY successfully.

Now I insert my USB KEY, called PENDRIVE (F:/) automatically, in my other laptop (installed on Ubuntu 8, but I can not just upgrade since the internet connection does not seem to work). Unfortunately my computer I want to re-install on the new Ubuntu has not the possibility to boot on the USB port (if I click on F12 I have 3 options: HDD, DVD, external disk), therefore it boots on Ubuntu 8. No pb, I can try to reboot after. But when I enter the USB KEY, the system detects it is a bootable key, and requests if I want it to autorun. I answer Yes, of course, and it says "`Can not find autorun.exe`"

If I look in the key, there is file called wubi.exe, but it seems the system does not identify it.

Comment: You shouldn't post personal data like phone numbers on a PUBLIC internet site.

Comment: Have you tried the external disk option in the BIOS?

Comment: You don't want to try to run the USB key within Windows, which is wbhat I think you're doing. You want to select it at boot before Windows is even loaded.

Comment: Ubuntu 8 is a really old version, don't wanna use a newer version like 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [PLOP](http://www.plop.at/) - CD that allows you to boot from USB even if your Bios doesn't support it. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16822/boot-from-a-usb-drive-even-if-your-bios-wont-let-you/) is some more information.

Wubi.exe supports to run Ubuntu after Windows has already been booted. As the comments say, that is probably not what you really want and I assume you did try this as a secondary solution.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested I would think the external disk option in the bios could be the option to boot from the usb drive. If this does not work you could burn the iso image to a cd or dvd and boot from dvd.